# Git add all files including files matching in .gitignore

Tags: git

I am trying to import existing git and repo projects into a new single git repository.

There are many .gitignore files already checked in, and it is preventing me from importing the   files matching in the .gitignore file.

What I have done so far is delete all of the .gitignore files and then everything gets put in,  with a git add -A, and then I will put the .gitignore files back when I am done importing.

Is there some clever way to do this with command line options so I don't have to go through all of these extra steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try force-adding ignored files by using `git add -f .`, see the [help for git-add](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add.html).

Comment: I will give it a try.  Sounds like exactly what I need.